# Search path and Python virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtual-environment

I am working in a virtual environment in Python 3. I need to use a 3rd party module "mglearn" and I copy it to my virtual environment's lib/:

```
/home/abigail/environments/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mglearn
```

However, in ipython command line, it can't find the module name:

```
In [1]: import mglearn
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e19748f92cd9> in <module>()
----> 1 import mglearn

ImportError: No module named 'mglearn'
```

It should find it, right?

Then I checked my `sys.path`:

```
In [4]: print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/bin', '/usr/lib64/python35.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.5', '/usr/lib64/python3.5/plat-linux', '/usr/lib64/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/home/abigail/.ipython']
```

Why does `sys.path` only contain directories starting from the root `/`, not my virtual environment?  How can I get that module to be searched by Python?

Edited:

```
[abigail@localhost bin]$ ll activate
activate       activate.csh   activate.fish  
[abigail@localhost bin]$ ./activate
bash: ./activate: Permission denied
[abigail@localhost bin]$ sudo ./activate
sudo: ./activate: command not found
```

Strange! why is that?

Comment: How do you enter the virtualenv?

Comment: what do you mean? I just entered the virtual environ directory

Comment: You've created a virtual environment, but how do you actually use it? Do you run `. my_env/bin/activate` and then run `python`? Something else? You don't seem to be actually using it from your last code snippet.

Comment: Please see more info I just added.

Comment: `activate` isn't a script, you're not supposed to run it. You "source" it with `source path/to/activate` or `. path/to/activate`, which essentially runs the contained commands in your shell. All it does is add the virtualenv's `bin` folder to the beginning of your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Have you included correct config settings to your bash profile and sourced from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking for a virtual environment you will want to do an install to get the module you are looking to import to pre-pend correctly in your path variable at virtual environment activation time.  Consider trying this:

Since it looks like you already have a virtual environment set up, and it looks like you are using some form of Unix/Linux:

```
/home/abigail/environments/ $ source my_env/bin/activate
```

You should then see your terminal look something like:

```
(my_env) /home/abigail/environments
```

that means you have an active virtual environment.

Next you should install the module you want.  I am assuming that module is available via pip install.

```
(my_env) /home/abigail/environments $ pip install mglearn
```

This should get you all set up.  When you check your sys path you should now see at the front of it your virtual environement python stuffs.  And your import error should go away.

You may need to delete out the copy of mglearn you dropped into the directories manually if things get stuck.

Comment: Do I need to activate it every time?

Comment: You will want to activate it any time you are looking to use this module and anything else you set up in the virtual environment.  Yes.

Comment: Also, when you are done, be sure to enter "deactivate" to turn off the virtual environment.  Allowing the system to do it's tear down.

Comment: Is there a way to make it automatically activated, so that I don't have to type the command every time?

Comment: Why do I want to de-activate?

Comment: This becomes a question of do you want to be using a virtual environment at all then.  The virtual environment is often used to allow you to more readily control dependencies and allow you to test drive certain configurations without doing installs into your main interpreter package handling.  If that is not the goal here, you can forgo the virtual environment and just pip install mglearn.  Then you can code away merrily.

Deactivation is important if you plan on doing work (like installing modules) that you don't want reflected in your virtual environment.

Comment: why I can't see "deactivate" in the bin/ directory?

Comment: "deactivate" is contained inside of the "activate" file.  Meaning it only becomes a viable command inside of an active virtual environment.  The activate file allows for custom things to happen at activation and deactivation time.  But that is generally content for another question.

If my answer has helped you resolve your question/problem please do accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

VirtualEnv creates a clone of a Python installation and bakes an additional path into sys.path that point to the site-packages directory of a given virtualenv.

When you launch your IPython, it is likely installed in your main Python installation and does not know about any additional virtual environments you have created.

If you install IPython into a virtual environment, it will know about the site-packages location for that virtualenv. Try and run:

`which ipython`

Then look at your ipython script and you will see it begin with either:

`#!/usr/bin/python`

or:

`#!/home/abigail/environments/my_env/bin/python3`

The first indicates a globally installed ipython and the second is an ipython that has been installed into a specific virtualenv.

FYI, you can add paths to a Python interpreter by exporting the PYTHONPATH environment variable:

````
```export PYTHONPATH=/home/abigail/environments/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages```
````

This would let you use a globally installed IPython with your virtualenv. However, the typical way to do this would be to install a second copy of IPython in your virtualenv and use that copy.

````
```/home/abigail/environments/my_env/bin/ipython```
````

The `activate` shell commands for a virtualenv only do two things:

1. Add the virtualenv Python interpreter to your PATH. So when you type `python3` you run `/home/abigail/environments/my_env/bin/python3` instead of `/usr/bin/python3`. It is this binary at `/home/abigail/environments/my_env/bin/python3` which will automatically include the `/home/abigail/environments/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages` location on the sys.path.
2. Change your PS1 environment variable so your terminal has a prompt to remind you which virtualenv you are working in.

It is up to you to use the `activate` shell script or not (as it's just very simple helper script, you can adjust environment in whatever way makes sense to you). If you are only using one virtualenv, you can add exports to your ~/.bashrc file instead, e.g.:

````
```export PATH=/home/abigail/environments/my_env/bin/:$PATH```
````

Would automatically make `python3` run your virtualenv Python the same as running `source activate` within your virtualenv.

Comment: in testing it doesn't appear to automatically add the "site-packages" directory in the virtual_env. I think the virtual_env folder replicates the directory structure of the /usr folder. So when the virtual environments python interpreter does it's default search path, it finds the site-packages first int he virtual environment's directory structure.