# Are Anaconda’s best practices the way to set a python environment that needs financial functions found at Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, flask-login, flask-migrate

My (Mac) environment has evolved into an unusable state after adding Flask-Login and Flask-Migrate, just like Anaconda illustrates here: https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/. They say that conda 4.6.0 would work it out but I have conda 4.6.1 and it is unusable. I need financial functions that I could only find at Anaconda. Did anybody take the best practices that Anaconda suggests successfully or have other ideas?

Comment: Which specific packages do you need? The general advice is to create a new environment that contains the minimal set of packages that you need, especially if you're using pip to install packages.

Comment: Thanks. Need at least these: alembic==1.0.10
astroid==2.2.5
certifi==2019.3.9
Click==7.0
configparser==3.7.4
dataclasses==0.6
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-Migrate==2.4.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.0
isort==4.3.20
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.1
Mako==1.0.11
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1
nelson-siegel-svensson==0.3.0
numpy==1.16.3
pylint==2.3.1
PyMySQL==0.9.3
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-editor==1.0.4
scipy==1.3.0
six==1.12.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.3
typed-ast==1.3.5
Werkzeug==0.14.1
wrapt==1.11.1
xlrd==1.2.0

Comment: And which are not available on conda? Flask-Login and Flask-Migrate? In what way is the environment unusable? Is there an error message? Did you install all the pip packages last? What exact commands did you use?

Comment: I cannot import flask_login or flask_migrate, that is the error. Flask-Login and Flask-Migrate are available on conda. I found them later after I had installed with pip. I tried to install via conda too. They even showed on my virtual environment from channel Anaconda. I have been coding and installing based on the latest need and got to this point

Comment: If they're available with conda, you should definitely install them that way. At this point, I think the best thing to do is remove the environment that's causing the problem and recreate it, which is listed as one of the best practices in the article you linked to. `conda env remove -n env-name` and `conda create -n env-name dependencies=version`

Comment: conda create -n myenv flask-login did it! I started by flask-login to try this critical package first. The creation installed python 3.7.3 and various other packages. Although vscode flags import flask_login as a problem (maybe a pylint issue that never happened before, and I will get to it later) it now passes by the import flask-login command. I will try flask-migrate next and then the other necessary packages (numpy, etc.). Many thanks for your support!

Comment: Solved based on @Steve D. advice on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40876767/search-path-and-python-virtual-environment. "You may need to delete out the copy of <package> you dropped into the directories manually if things get stuck."

Deleting numpy from the project directory stopped the error. I do not know how numpy ever got the project directory.